# can't commit changes in xcode 4

Tags: xcode, svn, xcode4, commit

i set up a project to be on version control. I imported the project without problems to the server repository. Now, when i commit changes, they seem to be committed as i don't get any errors and it says "Committing" but when i go to check the changes in the repository, i noticed that the changes are not there, so there was no commit even if xcode said it committed. Has anyone had this issue? I don't know where to look to fix it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is your problem, but I would check if Xcode is using your repository or one it set up itself. Look at Repositories in the Organizer window and see if there's anything there you don't want. If there is, you'll have to remove it from that list and delete the hidden .git folder in the project's directory.

Comment: the thing is that i can import my project into the repository, then i check it and the project is there. But i just cant commit, nothing happens. So the question is, do i need to install any plugin to make the commit or svn to work?

Answer (score 1):

Problem fixed! The solution was to erase the project from my hard drive and do a checkout from the repository. That way subversion would know which project was under version control.